# Are there remote administration tools for iPad? Preferably screen sharing

Tags: ipad, screen-sharing, remote-control

I have an elderly friend who has an iPad and calls every few days with problems. Doing remote tech support over the phone is getting tedious.

Is there anything available for iPad that's comparable to the Mac-to-Mac screen sharing options? Searching Google only turned up apps that let you administer a Mac from an iPad.

Comment: Does your elderly friend has a Mac?

Comment: He does, but we switched him to iPad hoping it would be easier for him.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably recommend the Teamviewer app for iOS.

Full instructions found [here](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-can-I-share-the-screen-on-my-iPad-iPhone-with-TeamViewer/ta-p/4734).

It is Free and you can download it from [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/teamviewer-quicksupport/id661649585#?platform=ipad)

For your specific case read this

[How to Get Started with Mobile to Mobile Connections!](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Community-Blog/How-to-Get-Started-with-Mobile-to-Mobile-Connections/ba-p/1769)

That will allow you screen sharing but not Control since iOS does not allow remote control at this time.

But there is an exception.
You can connect to any iOS based devices with TeamViewer for Remote Control for iOS. This feature, however, is limited to connections to apps that have the TeamViewer **[Screen sharing SDK](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/for-developers/screen-sharing-sdk/)** for iOS integrated.

Therefore, only screen sharing is possible for connections from a mobile device to an iOS app.

On the Supported iOS App

This functionality is based on the implementation of the Screen sharing SDK by the app developer and meant for them to support their app on an iOS device.

Therefore, it is only necessary to initiate a support request from within the supported app.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I looked at, but as far as I can tell, it lets you administer a Mac from an iPad, but not the other way around. If I'm wrong about that, then this is the answer I was looking for; let me take a look at the instructions.

Comment: @EdwardFalk I have updated my post with link hopefully answering your question.

Comment: Aha! I'd downloaded TeamViewer Remote Control when what I really wanted was TeamViewer QuickSupport.

Comment: OK, I tried it out. It lets me *see* the iPad, but it doesn't let me *control* it. It's still a huge improvement, since at least I can see what's on my friend's screen, but I'm still hoping there's a way to control it too.

Comment: I believe that Apple (currently) does not allow remote control of iOS devices. Hopefully they will come to their senses, till then the solution you have is likely the best of many bad choices.